# How to find MAX of COUNT Result for Relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, max

I have Table which consist of PatientId which is Int  and Date which is Date Data Type.

It does look like following

```
patientId   Date
  101       01/01/2001
  102       01/02/2001
  103       01/03/2002
  104       01/03/2004
  105       01/03/2004
  106       01/04/2004
```

And My Desired Result would give me

```
Count   Year
3       2004
```

since it has the most patients, also it we have two year that has the same number of patients then we should have  both year displayed with Number of patients that they had.
Thank you.

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`YEAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186313.aspx) function to extract year from your `date` column. Use extracted year in `group by` to get the `count` of Year

```
select TOP 1 year([Date]),count(1) as [Count]
from Yourtable
Group by year([Date])
Order by [Count] desc
```

Another way would be using [`DATEPART`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
select TOP 1 Datepart(year,[Date]),count(1) as [Count]
from Yourtable
Group by Datepart(year,[Date])
Order by [Count] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DATEPART` function is your friend in this case. However, to get all of the rows in case of a tie, a simple `TOP` will not work. In this case, a different coding method is needed.

You could use a `RANK()` command, but that is more complex than this calls for. Instead, use a Common Table Expression (CTE).

Here, I set up a table for testing. Since I need two years with the same count of rows, I extended your sample into 2005

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    custID INT,
    [Date] DATE
    )  

TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable;

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES 
  (101, '01/01/2001'),
  (102, '01/02/2001'),
  (103, '01/03/2002'),
  (104, '01/03/2004'),
  (105, '01/03/2004'),
  (106, '01/04/2004'),
  (107, '02/01/2005'),
  (108, '02/02/2005'),
  (109, '10/10/2005');
```

This is the CTE I created, which summarizes the data into its year counts, and the queries against the CTE.

```
WITH MyData AS (
    SELECT
        DATEPART(year, [Date]) AS [Year],
        COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Datepart(year, [Date])
    )
-- Now we issue the SELECT statement against the CTE itself

SELECT *
FROM MyData
WHERE ct = (SELECT MAX(ct) FROM MyData)
```

And here is the output:

```
Year    ct
2004    3
2005    3
```